# Automatically change sheets (tabs) by time-based trigger script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use Google Sheets as slideshow with the sheets (tabs). My code is below. In cell A201 (range 201,1) there is the name of the next sheet (tab). When I run the function "SlideShow()" alone, it works perfectly, switching to the next tab named in cell A201.

But, the time-based trigger does not work. I tried creating manually in code (as the function "Temporizador()" bellow) and clicking in the clock button in the script editor. Both doesn't work.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
function onOpen()
        {
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu
          (
            "Apresentação",
            [
              {name: "Testar", functionName: "SlideShow"},
              {name: "Ativar Slides", functionName: "Temporizador"}
            ]
           );
        }

function SlideShow() {

      var valor = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(201,1).getDisplayValue();

      var planilha = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(valor).activate();

      var teste = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(valor).getRange(1,1).activate();

    }

function Temporizador() { 

     ScriptApp.newTrigger("SlideShow").timeBased().everyMinutes(1).create();

    }
```

Comment: I have a complete solution available at this URL: https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/sheetshow. Are use the JavaScript timer to do all the timing.

Comment: Thank you! It works. But, is there a way to hide the control panel after pressing start button? I'm using a smart TV (own limited browser) to show some data in various sheets. The idea is to leave the TV slideshowing the sheets with the data.

Comment: @WagnerKobayashi did you mange to create the script? the link provided is broke